# HttpContext.SignInAsync not starting a new session for database users in identity server 4

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I want to validate and use my database users in identity server 4.Here is my customized login code in Account Controller.

```
     if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // validate username/password against my user repository class, and get the user's info
            var user = await _users.FindAsync(model.Username, model.Password);
            if(user != null)
            {
               
                await _events.RaiseAsync(new UserLoginSuccessEvent(user.LoginId, user.SubjectId, user.FullName, clientId: context?.Client.ClientId));

                AuthenticationProperties props = null;
                if (AccountOptions.AllowRememberLogin && model.RememberLogin)
                {
                    props = new AuthenticationProperties
                    {
                        IsPersistent = true,
                        ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.Add(AccountOptions.RememberMeLoginDuration)
                    };
                };

               
                var isuser = new IdentityServerUser(user.SubjectId)
                {
                    DisplayName = user.FullName,
                    AdditionalClaims=user.Claims.ToList(),
                    AuthenticationTime=DateTime.UtcNow
                };

                await HttpContext.SignInAsync(isuser, props);

                if (context != null)
                {
                    if (context.IsNativeClient())
                    {
                        return this.LoadingPage("Redirect", model.ReturnUrl);
                    }

                    return Redirect(model.ReturnUrl);
                }

                // request for a local page
                if (Url.IsLocalUrl(model.ReturnUrl))
                {
                    return Redirect(model.ReturnUrl);
                }
                else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.ReturnUrl))
                {
                    return Redirect("~/");
                }
                else
                {
                    // user might have clicked on a malicious link - should be logged
                    throw new Exception("invalid return URL");
                }
            }

            await _events.RaiseAsync(new UserLoginFailureEvent(model.Username, "invalid credentials", clientId:context?.Client.ClientId));
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, AccountOptions.InvalidCredentialsErrorMessage);
        }
```

I have created the Profile service class and configured the startup class like this

```
    services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddInMemoryClients(InMemoryConfig.GetClients())
                .AddProfileService<ProfileService>()
                .AddInMemoryApiScopes(InMemoryConfig.GetApiScopes())
                .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(InMemoryConfig.GetIdentityResources())
                .AddDeveloperSigningCredential();
        
        services.AddTransient<IProfileService, ProfileService>();
        services.AddTransient<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();
```

But the user session never starts, takes me back to the login page and Profile service never gets called.
Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, guys my bad. This problem arises when SSL is disabled for my identity server 4 application. I enabled SSL for my application and everything started working fine.